# Using a dependecy as both a concrete implementation and as a mock in the same TestFixture

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit, moq, autofixture

I have a `TestFixture` class that exercises some code in my current project. Most of the time, I feed the actual, concrete implementation of some of the dependencies to the SUT. However, I came across a case in which using the real thing would be undesirable. Since I'm using a custom `AutoDataAttribute` to create the SUT, it seems now I've lost the ability to substitute the dependency I want for a mock, unless I create all the details by hand.

The SUT gets all its dependecies via constructor injection:

```c#
public class MyService {
  private readonly IDependency dependency;

  public MyService(IDependency dependency, ...) {
    ...
    this.dependency = dependency ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
    ...
  }
}
```

This is what my test class looks like:

```c#
[TestFixture]
public class MyServiceTest {
  [Test, CustomAutoMock]
  public void TestCase1(int id, MyService sut) {
    ...
    sut.Dependency.Configure( ... );
    ...
    sut.DoSomethingWith(id);
    ...
    }

  [Test, CustomAutoMock]
  public void TestCase2(string searchString, MyService sut) {
    ...
    sut.Dependency.Configure( ... );
    ...
    sut.FindSomethingMatching(searchString);
    ...
    }

  ...

  [Test, CustomAutoMock]
  public void TestCaseN([Frozen] Mock<IDependency> mockDependency, MyService sut) {
    ...
    mockDependency.SetUp(o => o.DoSomething()).Throws<InvalidOperationException>();
    ...
    sut.Exercise();
    ...
    }
}
```

And this is the CustomAutoMockAttribute:

```c#
class CustomAutoMockAttribute : AutoDataAttribute {
  public CustomAutoMockAttribute() : base(InitializeCustomFixture) { }

  public static Fixture InitializeCustomFixture() {
    var fixture = new Fixture();

    fixture.Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization { ConfigureMembers = true });

    ...

    fixture.Register<IDependency>(() => fixture.Create<ConcreteDependency>());

    ...

    return fixture;
  }
}
```

Actually `MyService`'s constructor takes 18 parameters! (Don't look at me like that, this is *legacy* code that was passed down to me ) That's one of the main reasons why AutoFixture has been such a great time saver in trying to get this code under control bit by bit.

In `MyServiceTest.TestCaseN`, I expected the SUT to get the mocked dependency, but no matter what, it always gets an instance of `ConcreteDependency`.

Is there any way I can configure AutoFixture to feed `mockDependency` into the SUT *without* me having to create everything by hand?

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking perhaps you are not trying to fix the right problem.

Make sure your 18 injected dependencies are services you *actually* depend on.

Maybe you can abstract a handful of them away behind a single service that will focus on a specific responsibility.

Abstracting away a given concern is a great way to make sure you don't end up with gigantic constructors. And it should be doable to refactor to reduce the number of dependencies, even on legacy code. (If it already has dependency injections, at least it's not *that* horrible for legacy code :P

On the other hand, it's always good to automate boilerplate arrange code.

Back in the day, I started writing a roslyn plugin to generate the injected mocks. I don't know what's the current state of affairs with Visual Studio 2019, but maybe it can help.

https://github.com/salfab/moqlyn/tree/develop

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is what I ended up doing, and even if it's not really pretty, it works:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyServiceTest {

  //...

  [Test, CustomAutoMock]
  public void TestCaseN(Fixture fixture, Mock<IDependency> mockDependency) {
    //...

    mockDependency
        .SetUp(o => o.DoSomething())
        .Throws<InvalidOperationException>();

    fixture.Inject(mockDependency.Object);
    var sut = fixture.Create<MyService>();

    //...

    sut.Exercise();

    //...

  }
}
```

I know 18 dependencies sounds crazy. I'm feeling the pain for that, but at least with this I can slowly start putting this code base under test, which I hope will allow me to refactor some sense into it later.

Comment: It's hard to tell without the code of the .ctor of MyService: how can autofixture instantiatie the instance of the proper implementation in the injected dependency ? are you using interfaces or concrete classes in the .ctor ?